# Why aren't these transitions working? (CSS3 / jQuery)

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, css-transitions

I'm relatively new to CSS3 and I've gotta get this done so please forgive the horrendous code. All I am trying to do is make an off-canvas menu with an accordion navigation (actually, I want it to be horizontal navigation for desktop, off-canvas for mobile but that's another story..).  https://jsfiddle.net/StephanieQ/uk0902qx/1/
I'm using jQuery's slideUp/Down method to achieve these effects but the transitions just aren't there.  If I specify a time as an argument to the function, the animation just hesitates for that duration.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("nav h3").click(function(){
        $("nav ul ul").slideUp();
        if(!$(this).next().is(":visible"))
        {
            $(this).next().slideDown();
        }
    });
});
```

I'm sure the reason is obvious, but I really can't see it. And I'd also prefer to use toggleClass or something like that so it would fit in better with my media queries.  Any help would be wonderful!

(The ugly red box represents a logo -- Bonus question: Why does the image just pop over rather than transition like everything else?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really interesting problem.

You defined a bunch of transitions on the element that you wanted to slide up and down.

```
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
```

That doesn't work with JQuery's slideDown() method because slideDown rapidly changes the height value.  Every time that value changes - thousands of times - CSS tries to take .25 seconds to execute that transition. Thus, nothing happens on each minute iteration and the transition appears to occur all at once.

To fix the problem, either remove those transitions or use jQuery to toggle a class like you mentioned.  I went with the first approach - removing the CSS transitions.

The working fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/uk0902qx/4/

Comment: geez, I've been trying to figure this out for like 20 mins now! I even commented out the transitions in CSS. My problem was I did the top first, tested, didn't work, commented out the part in `nav ul ul {...}`, tested, didn't work. I didn't think to try them both commented out. Nice job

Comment: Haha, I've been stuck trying to solve it too. Actually the very first thing I did was comment transitions on * but I didn't realize she ALSO put transitions on the ul itself. Anyway, putting transitions on all elements doesn't seem like a sensible idea to me (performance-wise for mobile but also because of the unpredictability of it).

Comment: Aah! Thank you so much! To be perfectly honest I kind of volunteered to do a website for my friend's event so I'm scrambling to get things done.  I think if I had spent my time learning CSS3 transitions properly rather than doing things through 'trial and error madness', I would have saved time..  The transitions on all elements thing was something I got from a tutorial and didn't really understand what it did.  Again, thank you so much! I'm learning a lot :)

Comment: Yeah, if you're doing this kind of front end work, for me at least, the more you work with the web inspector, the better off you are.  Hopefully you know what the web inspector is.  Anyway, good luck.  The site doesn't look bad and the experience can be invaluable.